# Where does the GCC flag -Os come from on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, homebrew, automake

I'm trying to install CurlPP, but it seems to put "-Os" in the CXXFLAGS. Then, it tries to remove the optimization flag, but the regex is -O[0-9] in automake doesn't match the 's'. This is causing builds to fail.

Where does this "-Os" come from? Is this a legitimate optimization flag, or what?

How can I change CXXFLAGS on my machine with homebrew?

Answer (score 1):

`-Os` is optimise for size. It's pretty [standard on any C compiler](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) to be honest. Perhaps just change the regex?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, I have the same problem, but I had no idea why it complains about some 's' in command line!
The fix is really simple: run `brew edit curlpp`, then insert line

`ENV.remove_from_cflags(/-O./)`

at the beginning of the install function in the script. That turns off the optimization though, so you may find better solution. But the package installs well.

Comment: Oh, I've just found this bug in Homebrew's tracker, the problem is in curlpp code, but it's not very active project, so there is no patch from them.